# Strange ESLinting in VSCode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

I've set up ESLint fixAll option on save in my VSCode Vue project. Here is the editor's settings:

```
// ESLint vs. Prettier
"[javascript]": {
  "editor.formatOnSave": false
},
"[vue]": {
  "editor.formatOnSave": false
},
"eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.fixAll.eslint": true
},
```

But now ESLint formats my code step-by-step. It corrects only one code issue with each Cmd+S hitting. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-t2yY07o8WM). How to setup VSCode to fixAll with one Cmd+S hitting?